# How can I force a file to be opened in a new instance of the application?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var p = Process.Start("file.xlsx");
p.WaitForExit();
```

If Excel is already running, the file will be opened in that instance and `p` will be `null` and therefore I can't wait for exit. How can I force the file to be opened in a new instance of the application?

Comment: until you exit the excel file that you have opened or save it etc... then what would you expect..?

Comment: I'm not sure you can - even trying manually with the `excel.exe` it seems like it will always detect the running instance and "work with it", rather than spinning up an entire new instance.  Perhaps there are some command line parameters that can be passed...

Comment: ... [indeed there are](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Microsoft-Office-products-079164CD-4EF5-4178-B235-441737DEB3A6#ID0EAABAAA=Excel) - see `/x`.

Comment: Ok, so I guess it's not possible to generalize it for any application.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office\Office12\excel.exe" /x "path_to_your_file.xlsx"`

C#

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Excel.exe";
psi.Arguments = @"/x ""C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\abc.xlsx";
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

The subfolder `/Office12` depends on the office version you're using.